# Report data, techniques to store summarized results instead of raw data

Tags: sql-server, math, statistics, reporting

What techniques/tips can you give in regards to summarizing report data points so you don't have to store the raw data in the database?

For example, if I was storing page view traffic for a website, and my reports were accurate to the hour I could roll-up all database rows by the hour, and then possible even create further summary tables by the various increments like per day/month etc.

Any other tricks/tips along these lines?

Comment: If you capture the raw data I would want to keep it.  The metrics you run now may not be sufficient down the road and you'll regret not having that raw info to go back to.

Comment: I agree with JNK - unless you've really got so much data that you can't store it, keep the raw data!  Speaking as a statistician, nothing activates my death stare like pre-aggregated data.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about data warehousing / data mining. You still need OLTP ("the raw") data in a database, but you'd create an additional OLAP data warehouse with "pre-crunched" numbers for faster report access. However, this is an expensive venture in dollars and time - definitely not suitable for web site statistics unless you were Google or Amazon. So you are better off just keeping the setup that you have, and use your queries to summarize data.